# ()=>{ ; error in .Net tasks

Tags: c#, lambda, task

I started to play around with .Net tasks, I'm getting this error `()=>{ ; expected` and don't know why:

**EDIT:**

Here's my code:

```
private void create_alias_button_Click(object sender , RoutedEventArgs e)
{           
   System.Threading.Tasks.Task t = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => { addAliasDomains()});
    t.Wait();
}

private void addAliasDomains()
{
    string pathToAddAliasScript = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["pathToAddAliasScript"];
    Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
    runspace.Open();
    using (PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        foreach (string s in domains_listBox.Items)
        {
            PSCommand command = new PSCommand();
            powershell.AddCommand(_pathToSourcesFolder + "\\" + pathToAddAliasScript);
            powershell.AddParameter("alias" , s);
            powershell.Runspace = runspace;
            Collection<PSObject> results = powershell.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include actual code, rather than image of the code. Please read [ask].

Comment: It's expecting a semicolon before the close curly bracket.

Comment: using `{....}` in a lambda expression you open up a new code-block and in these blocks every statement has the terminated by the `;` terminator.

Comment: Although a simpler solution would be to use `Task.Run(() => addAliasDomains());` or possibly even `Task.Run(addAliasDomains)`

Comment: you just need to put `;` or you just remove `{}`

Comment: An additional remark: If you use Tasks, don't use Wait. If you need to use Wait, don't use Tasks.